# Ajuste de curvas de crecimiento sigmoidales en R

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de ajustar una curva de acumulación de nutrientes y materia seca de maíz en R.
Se que la curva que describe es sigmoidal y que la acumulación de materia seca o de los nutrientes depende del tiempo.
Mi primera duda es como ajusto y gráfico esto en R y luego, teniendo varias curvas de distintos tratamientos, como comparo las curvas entre si.
Paso algo de lo que escribi en R y algunos datos en un enlace:

```
dataT1 <- subset(C, Trat == "T1")
dataT3 <- subset(C, Trat == "T3")
dataT7 <- subset(C, Trat == "T7")

plotPoints(MS ~ Dia, data = dataT1)

MST1 <- nls(MS ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (Dia - d)))), data = dataT1, start = list(a = min(MS), 
                                                                   b = max(Dia), c = 1, d = round(median(MS))), trace = TRUE)
```

Al escribir esto me salta el error `Error in typeof(x) : objeto 'MS' no encontrado`

Database:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxt2t6sfs52ilq3/database_dudas.xlsx?dl=0

Muchas gracias!

Comment: German, bienvenido, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask], tu pregunta es algo amplia deberías complementarla con una muestra de los datos y agregar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora. Saludos.

Comment: Patricio, muchas gracias por la bienvenida y por tu respuesta. Vi los enlaces que me mandaste y edite mi pregunta según tus sugerencias. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondo puntualmente al error que estás teniendo. El problema lo tienes en el parámetro `start`, estas construyendo una lista de valores iniciales, pero tienes que tener en mente que ese objeto `list` esta fuera del "scope" de `nls()`, de modo que el parámetro `data = dataT1` no significa nada para la lista, debes construir la invocación de la siguiente forma:

```
MST1 <- nls(MS ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (Dia - d)))), 
            data = dataT1, 
            start = list(a = min(dataT1$MS), 
                      b = max(dataT1$Dia), 
                      c = 1, 
                      d = round(median(dataT1$MS))
                      ), 
            trace = TRUE)
```

Es decir especificando el "path" completo al objeto, es decir `dataT1$MS` o `dataT1$Dia`). De todas formas, al menos con los datos que has publicado, tienes otro error, pero en este caso con la elección de los valores iniciales, eso en todo caso lo tendrás que analizar.

Comment: Patricio, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Es verdad que ahora me da otro error, aunque no lo entiendo del todo, por bibliografía estos datos se tienen que ajustar a una curva sigmoide según estos parámetros, entonces ¿por qué el R me da error?

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la respuesta con este codigo:

```
plotPoints(MS ~ Dia, data = dataT1)
MST1 <- nls(MS ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (Dia - d)))),
            data = dataT1,
            start = list(a = min(dataT1$MS),
                         b = max(dataT1$MS),
                         c = 1, d = median(dataT1$Dia)),
            trace = TRUE, algorithm = "port")

overview(MST1)
plotfit(MST1, smooth = TRUE)
```

Muchas gracias a todas las personas que me dieron una mano.